# How GridLayout computes Composite size

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

In an SWT application, I have a composite with a `GridLayout` that has two columns. The first contains labels, the second texts and checkboxes. I use `TextLayout`s for some of them and paint them manually (in a paint listener), so I have to manually compute their sizes. I set the computed sizes for the widgets with `setSize()` and set `widthHint` and `heightHint` in their respective `GridData`s. `GridData` objects for the labels (1st column of the grid) are created with `(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false)` and for the widgets in the 2nd column with `(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false)`. The `computeSize()` for the widgets returns the sizes I expect (eg. no more then 68 pixels of width for the 1st column and 128 for the 2nd).

But the `computeSize()` for the `Composite` returns a width that is much larger than I expect to see (or want), namely 253, while I expect 68 + 128 + 3 * 4 + 2 * 2 = 212 or something near to it.
The `pack()` on the `Composite`, acccordingly, makes it grow much wider than I want. I can force the required width of the `Composite` with the `setSize()`, but subsequent actions on the shell containing my composite invoke the composite's `pack()` anyway, so its width gets spoiled. Setting of the `widthHint` of the composite's `GridData` won't work either.

The `Composite` itself is a child of a upper-level `Composite` with `GridLayout` and has a `GridData` with `(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, true)`.

Why the `computeSize()` decides that the width of the `Composite` should be 253, if the widths of the widgets in the columns are computed to be 68 and 128 pixels wide and their `widthHints` are set correspondingly? How does it work? What does it take into account, besides the computed sizes of the child widgets? Where can I find a description of its algorithm (the source of the `GridLayout`'s `layout (Composite composite, boolean move, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean flushCache)`, which actually computes the size, is rather complicated and difficult to understand) ?

How can I make the layout managers keep the required width of the `Composite` while changing layout of the parent `Composite`s, including the `Shell` (on resizing, font changes etc)?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you maybe upload a screenshot of what it currently looks like and a mockup of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Trying to find how to upload pictures... It's the first day I'm here

Comment: @Baz, I have not enough reputation to upload pictures.

Comment: But you can upload them somewhere else and post the links here.

Comment: I want to have a composite of an exact width, that I calculate manually based on currently used fonts (that may change dynamically). I have to know exact sizes and locations of the widgets in order to align with them widgets in adjacent composites, but the pack() cahnge these sizes and locations unpredictably and I can't control it. I wold like just to understand it's logics.

Comment: This is what it should look like: http://i70.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0810/46/fe98a76e7e95b04e88202dd1a5513446.png. It is the previous version, with statically defined sizes and fonts. It works fine. Now I try to change fonts at runtime and recalculate the sizes and locations of the GUI elements, and this is what I get: http://i70.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0810/05/d0bafc2e20b21eacdb7c9c1b15a6bc05.png. The background colors are just to see where the comosite borders lie. Now I work on the composite with the cyan background. The yellow is also incorrect, but it's not a problem.

Comment: The size designated with the arrow is 181 while it should be 166. I would like to make it what it should be or at least to understand why it turns to be 181.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridLayout` is full of surprises. If you are not dogmatically stuck to it, I recommend switching to `FormLayout`. This is much more powerful and gives you much much more control over the final result of your UI. It is a paradigm shift compared to `GridLayout`, but it is very much worth learning it.

With `FormLayout`, you can use the dimensions of the parent, or the position and dimensions of any sibling `Controls` (ie. `Controls` sharing the parent) for positioning and sizing controls. It's like declaring a couple of layouting constraints per control and the manager will do its best to satisfy your wishes.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/eclipse-rcp-layout-view-with-formlayout/) for you to get you started. It introduces you to `FormData`, which declares four anchor points (top, bottom, right, left) and the `FormAttachments` which define the constraints in a `FormData` object.

For your problem, you can layout the first column as using eg. 40% of the width of the parent, with each row being placed below the label of the previous row. The controls of the second column are placed relative to their label (on their left) and the label or control of the previous row (on their top).

Now what seems to bother you is the width of some of the controls in the second column. In `FormLayout`, you can set an explicite constraint for the right anchor, either by declaring it to be eg. at 100% width of the parent (starting from the 40% right anchor of the first column) which will then rely on the layout of the parent's parent, or by setting the right anchor as an absolute margin in pixels counting from the right edge of the first column. This can be done by referencing the label in the first column, but switching the alignment. This is necessary because by default, a relation from the right anchor of `Control` A to a sibling B will automatically use the left side of B. In code, this second possibility will spell out like that:

```
FormData fd;
//row 1
Label lblC1R1;
Control ctrlC2R1;
//row 2
Label lblC1R2;
Control ctrlC2R2;

...

fd = new FormData(); //for ctrlC2R2;
fd.top = new FormAttachment(lblC1R1);  //top edge clings to (y-coord of) bottom of row 1 label (could reference row 1 control, too)
fd.left = new FormAttachment(lblC1R2); //left edge clings to right side of row 2 label
fd.right = new FormAttachment(lblC1R2, 200, SWT.RIGHT); //right edge is defined as a distance of +200 px from *right* side of row 2 label (by default, it would use the left side)
//we don't set fd.bottom, so the control may grow or shrink with ie. font size

ctrlC2R2.setLayoutData(fd);
```

This will fix the width of the second column control to 200px starting from the right side of the first column, no matter what the control says about its preferred size.

Comment: thank you very much for your benevolent and detailed advice. It is reasonable, and In the next project I will use a FormLayout. I have to say that I've stated this one with 'FormLayouts' in some of the composites, but have decided at some point that using 'GridLayouts' in all of the composites will lead to a more straitforward and clear code. Currenty after some work I have found a solution with `GridLayout`s that works well and satisfies me. In brief, I should carefully avoid any calls of `*.laout()` before the final `layout()` and `setSize()` on the main shell.